# Is it possible to add modifiers dynamically with animation nodes?

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes

To add modifiers dynamically, I know that one can modify values of existing modifier via attribute output node. Can this node be used to create modifiers or does it need some sort of scripting?

Comment: try pressing I over the Eye Icon of the Modifier

Comment: sorry I dont know Animation Nodes but that would be the way I would try to do it

Comment: No that´s not the case. Needs to be added dinamically

Comment: but it would be not effectively there if you hide it. That was my thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is by using scripting, there are three important points to take into consideration when making this:

1. Make sure not to add the modifier if it was already added in a previous execution.
2. Output the input object and plug it into the attribute output node, making sure you are not editing a modifier before it gets added.
3. The modifier name should never be an empty text because then blender will automatically add a name and our first test will fail, so we should set a fallback value.

Making sure we got those three points right, we can write a code like this:

```
modifierName = modifierName if modifierName != "" else "Fallback"
if not modifierName in object.modifiers:
    object.modifiers.new(modifierName, 'ARRAY')
outObject = object
```

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Great!!! This was what I was looking for.