# Animation Nodes: Copy a selection/group of objects

Tags: objects, animation-nodes

I have several objects in a group. The objects are related to each other via modifiers. The modifiers are stuff like text objects following curves via the Curve modifier. If I select all of them and hist shift+D, then I can create a copy of the entire hierarchy, and the modifiers will automatically assign to the new version. For example, if I had TextObject with a curve modifier to CurveObject, then after duplicating, TextObject.001 will be on CurveObject.001.

You get the same behavior if you make a group instance and then explode it with Make Real. However, if you copy just one object at a time, then of course it still points to the previous version's curve. I can use the Object Instancer to make copies of single objects, but how do I do the whole lot? What's the proper way to go about this?

The overall goal is to copy the whole group, change some of the text in the text objects, then apply all modifiers and join the whole thing into 1 object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only recommend creating everything explicitly. So your node structure should be something like:

1. Instance all the objects you want, possibly using the *Copy All Option* or by disabling the *Copy From Source* option and injecting the object data later.
2. Loop over all your objects, add missing modifiers as described in my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93938/is-it-possible-to-add-modifiers-dynamically-with-animation-nodes), and set modifier values using *Attribute* nodes.